# Moment.Js confusion for displaying the date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I'm currently using moment js for my homework assignment and I have to display the date at the top of our day planner. This is currently what I am working with

```
 <body>
    <header class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-3">Work Day Scheduler</h1>
      <p class="lead">A simple calendar app for scheduling your work day</p>
      <p id="currentDay" class="lead"></p>
    </header>
```

In the #currentDay, I need to display the current day. This is what i'm using for that

```
var currentDayDisplay = document.getElementById(currentDay);
moment(currentDayDisplay).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

which simply isn't working, any idea why?

Comment: you may not even need momentjs to display a simple date like that. However, you should set the textContent property of the selected element to the target date.
`currentDayDisplay.textContent = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

```js
const currentDate = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY'); // get current date
document.getElementById("currentDay").textContent = currentDate; // display inside the element
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<p id="currentDay"></p>
```

Comment: This looks great, the only weird thing i'm getting now is it's saying "moment is not defined", know any workaround for this or if i'm not implementing it correctly?

Comment: You should import `moment.js` to your project to use `moment.js`

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script> this was actually already added to our starter HTML, which is mostly why I'm confused as to why i'm getting that error, also thank you for the help!!

Comment: See my updated answer, I added the moment.js from your link and it works. Check the import order. The moment.js should be loaded before your code execution

Comment: I'm definitely going to have to fiddle around, it's working fine in my console.log but i'm getting undefined right underneath the date, i moved the script links to the head of the html and that was able to get it console logged, it's just not displaying on my page. Lol I just wish I could use date fns for this :(